# How to retrieve array of objects sent by Ajax in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, axios

I am using Laravel with Vuejs and AXIOS for HTTP requests. I am sending a post request with the array of objects. So in my laravel store function how can I retrieve that data from the $request?

my questions array looks like:

```
             data:{
                questions:[{
                    question:'',
                    opt1:''
                            },
                     {
                 question:'',
                 opt1:''
                     }
                     ]
            }
```

Laravel Store method in controller:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
  return $request;

}
```

vue code:

```
axios.post('/addTest',this.$data.questions).then(response=>{
                    console.log(response.data);
                });
```

in this code questions is an array of objects.

Comment: Show the laravel code you have for `/addTest` now. (A route?)

Comment: @acdcjunior  /addTest is the route. i have tried to to return $request and check response in the console. it is showing objects. here: https://prnt.sc/iptd9g

Comment: Try: `$myArray = $request->all();` is this it?

Comment: How does your `questions` object (array?) look like?

Comment: @devk i have edited my question please check. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `this.$data.questions` is an array, you can simply use the `input()` method to pull all of the questions:

```
$questions = $request->input();
```

Let say you only want to pull the `question` property of the second item, you can do it like so in Laravel:

```
$secondQuestion = $request->input('1.question');
```

However, it would also be nice if you pass the questions as an object:

```
axios.post('/addTest', { questions: this.$data.questions });
```

And your PHP part will look like this:

```
$questions = $request->input('questions');
```

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: anybody knows ? how can i loop through this questions object in php?

Comment: @RakeshKohali The `$request->input()` method above should return an array. So you can simply use a basic `for` or `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel you have a store method and then you returning the request?Why you are doing that?To see the request from frontend? If so then I recommend you to use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com) for this.

Postman is easy to use and you can send a similar request that frontend sends.Then in laravel store function you can do

```
dd($request) //to output the request that postman sends
```

> You said: how can I retrieve that data from the $request

If you send from frontend something like

```
{ id: 1 }
```

Then in laravel you can do

```
$id = $request->get('id');
```

> Below you can see how i send a request with postman,and how output the request.
>
> Your request with postman

[image: send request with postman]

> Laravel code to output request

[image: laravel code to output the request]

> The response from Laravel displayed in postman

[image: Postman output]